# Fast append before string on each new line

Tags: string, append

I have a couple of pretty large text-files (1 GB each) which have one generated word on each line. I want to append a string before each of the generated words. Whether it's Java, C#, C, C++, or Ruby doesn't really matter. While I can't program this myself, I can compile and run it.

Example:

file.txt:

```
Aoos
ahsd
gAATa
sdFfg
```

output:

```
appendAoos
appendahsd
appendgAATa
appendsdFfg
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the tools you have available, you can use `sed`, `awk` or even `perl`:

```
sed 's/^/append/' inputFile >outputFile
awk '{print "append"$0}' inputFile >outputFile
perl -pne 's/^/append/' inputFile >outputFile
```

If you really want to write your own program, you can do filter programs relatively easy in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int ch, lastCh = '\n';
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (lastCh == '\n') printf ("append");
        putchar (ch);
        lastCh = ch;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just compile that as, for example, `myprog` and then run:

```
myprog <inputFile >outputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) from the command line, e.g.

```
$ sed 's/^/append/' < old_file.txt > new_file.txt
```